# Как запустить код заново при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: python, kivy

Делаю крестики нолики при помощи Kivy.
Задача при нажатии на кнопку обращаться к функции в которой надо что-то, что начнет заново код. Очистит текст кнопок и списки. Искал много, везде пишут про цикл, но мне не зациклить надо, а очистить все без выхода из программы. Как обратиться к функции я знаю, не знаю что в ней написать.

Comment: Надо сначала очистить свой разум, а затем очистить кнопки, списки...

Comment: Это реальный ответ или просто разговор?! Если реальный, то как мне через функцию build очистить кнопки. Как список очистить я понимаю. Как текст кнопок обновить, через функцию нажатия на кнопку?

Comment: Записать в неё пустую строку "".

Comment: Спасибо. Это я понимаю. Я не могу понять реальзацию. Я строю окно и кнопки в нем через стандартную функцию build , как мне к ней обратиться нажимая на кнопку "очистить поле". Если я сейчас скину код, мне начнут писать что я засоряю здесь. Не понимаю как задать вопрос более ясно.

Comment: А зачем вам все заново отстраивать? Я думаю достаточно просто очистить поля и сохраненные данные (списки).

Comment: Понял спасибо. Постараюсь. Если что задам вопрос как осистить поля.